# is jquery-ujs all I need to use jquery with rails 3?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

Will jquery-ujs give me all the helpers etc. that are used for all ajax helpers etc. that worked with prototype/script.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, all you need jquery-ujs's `rails.js` to replace original Prototype `rails.js` (and the jquery itself, to replace Prototype, but I assume you already have that).

Here's a [nice screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/205-unobtrusive-javascript) about UJS - see the [text version](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/205-unobtrusive-javascript) as well ("Swapping Framworks" part).

Comment: what about scriptalicious? i guess jquery has all plugins for that stuff?

Comment: You mean scriptaculous? Yeah, I guess you'd have to use some jquery plugins. [Here's a project](http://github.com/MrJoy/jrails) that seems like a complete solution. I'm not that much into jquery, so not 100% what would be the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a recent overview of [Rails' jQuery UJS](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/a-tour-of-rails-jquery-ujs/).

It adds progressive enhancements such as:

- Adding the ability to make POST, PUT, and DELETE requests from links
- Popping up confirmation dialogs when submitting forms
- Disabling links and buttons upon clicks to avoid double-clicks
- Turning forms into Ajax forms
- Turning file uploads into Ajax file uploads
- Adding Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF) protection to Ajax requests